# How to get the specific topics on HDP

Tags: gensim

Once I get topics for a document with lda[doc] I can print each topic using lda.print_topic(topic_id).

What's the equivalent way to retrieve topics for HdpModel?

One way I can think of is using hdp_to_lda to create an LdaModel. Is there a more straightforward way?

Answer (score 1):

If logging is on like this:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

then

```
hdp.print_topic()
```

will print the first 20 topics.

to print the first x documents

```
hdp.print_topic(x)
```

for example for the first 100:

```
hdp.print_topic(100)
```